# VB.Net Chart Equation and R² Value

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts, regression, equation

### Goal

I have a chart in Excel and I'm trying to replicate the same chart in VB.Net. I can get the chart data to be inputted correctly. I don't know how to retrieve the equation and R² value in a VB.Net chart control, as shown in my Excel chart.

---

### Current Problem

Here is the data that is gotten in my Excel graph and Vb.Net chart:

```
    ' X       Y
    '0.895, 120.1
    '0.978, 160.1
    '1.461, 240.1
    '1.918, 320.1
    '2.343, 400.2
    '2.769, 480.2
    '3.131, 560.2
    '3.493, 640.3
    '3.797, 720.3
    '4.089, 800.3
```

I get the following result from this (Excel):
[image: Excel Chart]

As you can see, I receive a formula **y= 203.83x - 62.797** and **R²=0.9949**
I'm trying to get the same result in Vb.Net but I am unable to find where this data is stored.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your goal is not clear.  Do you want to pull the displayed formula from the Excel trendline or do you want to now how to compute the formula in VB.Net.  If it is the former, then retrieve the Trendline.DataLabel.Text property (ex: `sheet1.ChartObjects.Item(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Item(1).TrendLines.Item(1).DataLabel.Text`).  If it is the latter, then research "least squares regression line" for the algorithm and implement it in your code.

Comment: @TnTinMn I'm looking for the  DataLabel text that is found in Excel, but for the VB.Net chart. There is no other way than to compute it?

Comment: If you are already using Excel then you can leverage the worksheet Formulas `SLOPE()` and  `INTERCEPT()`

Comment: @ScottCraner My Excel works correctly, I'm just trying to find the equivalent in VB.Net.

Comment: Then see here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?260106-Slope-function-help-needed

Comment: @ScottCraner This returns the slope. I tested it and the result gotten from the slope is nothing similar to y=203.83x - 62.797. I get 407.75 for the slope and -125.73 for the intercept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my issue. Here is the clsTrendline.vb that I fetched using the help of multiple people/threads/conversion websites/Excel help on this site.

```
Public Class Trendline

#Region "Variables"
Private m_Slope As Decimal
Private m_Intercept As Decimal
Private m_Start As Decimal
Private m_End As Decimal
Private m_RSquared As Decimal
#End Region

#Region "Properties"
Public Property Slope() As Decimal
    Get
        Return m_Slope
    End Get
    Private Set
        m_Slope = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Intercept() As Decimal
    Get
        Return m_Intercept
    End Get
    Private Set
        m_Intercept = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Start() As Decimal
    Get
        Return m_Start
    End Get
    Private Set
        m_Start = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property [End]() As Decimal
    Get
        Return m_End
    End Get
    Private Set
        m_End = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property RSquared As Decimal
    Get
        Return m_RSquared
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        m_RSquared = value
    End Set
End Property
#End Region

#Region "New..."
Public Sub New(yAxisValues As IList(Of Decimal), xAxisValues As IList(Of Decimal))
    Me.New(yAxisValues.[Select](Function(t, i) New Tuple(Of Decimal, Decimal)(xAxisValues(i), t)))
End Sub
Public Sub New(data As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of [Decimal], [Decimal])))
    Dim cachedData = data.ToList()

    Dim n = cachedData.Count
    Dim sumX = cachedData.Sum(Function(x) x.Item1)
    Dim sumX2 = cachedData.Sum(Function(x) x.Item1 * x.Item1)
    Dim sumY = cachedData.Sum(Function(x) x.Item2)
    Dim sumY2 = cachedData.Sum(Function(x) x.Item2 * x.Item2)
    Dim sumXY = cachedData.Sum(Function(x) x.Item1 * x.Item2)

    'b = (sum(x*y) - sum(x)sum(y)/n)
    '      / (sum(x^2) - sum(x)^2/n)
    Slope = (sumXY - ((sumX * sumY) / n)) / (sumX2 - (sumX * sumX / n))

    'a = sum(y)/n - b(sum(x)/n)
    Intercept = (sumY / n) - (Slope * (sumX / n))

    '    r = (n * (Exy) - (Ex * Ey)) / (((n * (Ex2) - (Ex) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 2)) * ((n * (Ey2) - (Ey) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 2)))
    RSquared = ((n * (sumXY) - (sumX * sumY)) / (((n * (sumX2) - (sumX) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 2)) * ((n * (sumY2) - (sumY) ^ 2) ^ (1 / 2)))) ^ 2

    Start = GetYValue(cachedData.Min(Function(a) a.Item1))
    [End] = GetYValue(cachedData.Max(Function(a) a.Item1))
End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Methods / Functions"
Public Function GetYValue(xValue As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return Intercept + Slope * xValue
End Function
#End Region

End Class
```

Hopefully this will help someone!